# Python Websocket that connects between client and another websocket

Tags: python, api, websocket

I have a program that creates multiple websocket connections to a third-party website. The problem is, that this website limits a websocket connection from the same account to only 1.
So I want to create an API (lets call it, `WssManager`) that my websockets will connect to. This  `WssManager` will create 1 single connection to the third-party API, and send the data received to all listening clients that will connect to it.

How can I achieve this? The `WssManager` needs to be able to get data from one WS server and send it to different WS client.

Appreciate any help as I could not find anything clear online.